# rotate cube smoothly in unity

Tags: c#-4.0, unityscript

Hi guys i need to rotate a cube smoothly without any lag in z direction but its not coming

## Here is my code

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class clockAnimator : MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
 
 }
 private const float 
  secondsToDegrees = 0.1f;
 public Transform seconds;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;

  //seconds.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f,(Time.Millisecond*-secondsToDegrees)*0.03f);
  seconds.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,0,Time.Millisecond*-secondsToDegrees);
 
 }
}
```

thanks in advance
Gokul

Comment: There isn't a question there. Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: try Time.deltaTime for smooth value changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate it smoothly I would recommend the Lerp function, there is a really good tutorial about it made by unity themselves:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD-mXwSCvWc

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:
1) Do it inside FixedUpdate()
2) Use deltaTime instead.